# npx create-react-app myApp does not work _npx\10796" as it does not contain a package.json file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to set my environment for React, but when I try to run the command `npx create-react-app myApp` I get the following error:

```
1) npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL

2) npm ERR! Could not install from "Guillen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\10796" as it does not contain a package.json file.

3) npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Andres Guillen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-25T01_16_30_068Z-debug.log

La instalación de [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] fracasó con código 1.
I have this node js version : 13.2.0 , npm version: 6.13.1
```

I don't know how to fix these errors, any ideas? Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a space character in the PC name *"Andres Guillen"* which is causing the problem.

Run:

- npm config set cache "C:\Users\ALEXAN~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
- npx create-react-app newapp

It's a workaround to ignore the space character.

Answer (score 0):

Check space in the global location - npx gives error if space in the path.

Run:

- npm install create-react-app   --(locally)
- npx create-react-app newapp

Thanks