# How can I fix error with react app creation?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

After run comand npx create-react-app projectName i've recieved this log, and app not created. Why this error happens?

npx: installed 99 in 8.22s
Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\12568\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\12568\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js from C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\12568\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\run-async\index.js is an ES module file
as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\12568\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\1
2568\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\package.json.

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61419971/npx-create-react-app-myapp-does-not-work-npx-10796-as-it-does-not-contain-a-pa/61420726#61420726)

Comment: Try this way - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428440/npx-create-react-app-not-working-must-use-import-to-load-es-module)

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to the changes that was introduced in: is-promise package version 2.2.0 (that is in node_modules of create-react-app) in which was added support for ES Module style default import, but in version 2.2.2, ESM support was removed because it turns out to be a breaking change.

Try this:

`npm install -g --force create-react-app`

to update the packages.